# finding specific row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table that holds two levels of rows, for example:

[image]

I have a button on each row of the first level, that executes JavaScript function, and pass the button to the function

```
onclick="js:BillingAddNewChildLine(this);"
```

I need a way to find inside the function (BillingAddNewChildLine) the last second level row under the first level row that button was clicked:

- if I click on the button of line 1 I should get line 1.2
- if I click on button on line 2 I should get line 2.2

this selector will return the last row of the table, is there any way to use jQuery selector in order to get what i need ?

```
$(".BillingTable > tbody tr:last")
```

many thanks

Comment: Please do not use `onclick` you should attach your javascript handlers with javascript not markup. Look up [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup) to find out more.

Comment: You can embed images just to let you know. No need to link to Google docs.

Comment: pllease show us your function BillingAddNewChildLine or try the next() function or children()

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to accomplish what you want if you give a "parent" class to all the parent(1st level) rows.

```
<tr class="parent">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><button>Get Last Child</button></td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
```

Then inside the onclick event of the buttons, you can get the final child(or 2nd level line, 1.2 and 2.2 in your example) using:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('.parent').last();
```

(new rows can be added using the `inserAfter` or `after` method, see the attached fiddle)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/fx4x8/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are dynamically creating the table but even if you are not, you can give every same level row a class like

```
<tr class="level-1">
   <td>
       <button class="btn" data-level="level-1"></button>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="level-1">
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="level-2">
   <td>
       <button class="btn" data-level="level-2"></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and then

```
$('btn').click(function(){
   var level = $(this).attr('data-level');
   var row = row.last();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this??

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zf5T/3/)

```
$('td').live('click', function(){
    tempval=parseInt($(this).html());
    newval=tempval+1;

    $(this).parents('table').append('<tr><td class="valuePlace">'+ newval +'</td><td>hi</td></tr>');
})
```

Comment: dear vignesh, thank you! that what i need but i want when i click on line 1, it should add a line 1.2 (because we have already 1.1), and the new line must be after 1.1 and not at end of the table.